# PostGIS ST_Intersects replace NULL value with 0

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'd like to count the number of points that interact with a given polygon using PostGIS.

Below is my query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(pt.geom) OVER w sum_of_pt
FROM pt, poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY poly.geom)
```

The query will return a NULL result if there is not any point interact with a polygon, but I need a solution to replace the NULL value with 0.

I have tried COALESCE(), but still got a null.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(COUNT(pt.geom) OVER w, 0) sum_of_pt
FROM pt, poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY poly.geom)
```

Is there any way to replace the NULL?

Comment: ST_Intersects is boolean and returns 0/1 but you filter out the zeroes by using `WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom)` because it is a shortcut for the TRUE case. Maybe you could rewrite the SQL and filter what ST_Intersects returns.

Comment: is this a 1 time query? or part of a larger process?

Comment: Well it is part of a process actually @ziggy

Comment: This may return **no rows** (which is *not* a `NULL` value!) - is that what you mean? If so, and if you are not interested in anything but the count, you can `SELECT SUM(sum_of_pt) AS sum_of_pt FROM (<your_exact_query> UNION ALL SELECT 0) q;`. However, your query is...uncommon, even if it works, and could be optimized for both cases when `poly` is a table of polygons, or a single static one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you place coalesce function, this way it works:

```
select coalesce( (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(pt.geom) OVER w sum_of_pt
FROM pt, poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY poly.geom)),0) sum_of_points;
```